# Generic method overload ambiguous with nullable types

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, ambiguous, overload-resolution

Say I have two generic, overloaded methods of the form:

```
public string Do<T>(T maybeValue, Func<T, string> func)
  where T : class
{
  if(maybeValue == null) return null;
  return func(maybeValue);
}

public string Do<T>(T? maybeValue, Func<T, string> func)
  where T : struct
{
  if(!maybeValue.HasValue) return null;
  return func(maybeValue.Value);
}
```

Now, calling the method with a variable of type nullable, C# refuses to compile and says that the call is ambiguous between the two overloads:

```
int? maybeX = 3;
Do(maybeX, x => x.ToString());
```

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   '`Program.Do<int?>(int?, System.Func<int?,string>)`' and
>   '`Program.Do<int>(int?, System.Func<int,string>)`'

Easy fixes are to include the generic parameter when calling the method, or to specify the type of the lambda argument:

```
Do<int>(maybeX, x => x.ToString());
Do(maybeX, (int x) => x.ToString());
```

Interestingely, choosing `int?` as generic type during invocation will not compile

> The type must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method".

How come? Obviously only one of the two overloads can be used with a value of type `int?`, yet the compiler says the call is ambiguous. Can I further constrain the methods to help the compiler decide which method to call, without having the invoking code specify the type explicitely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `where T : class` constraint is not part of the signature of the method. That check happens later in the method overload selection process.
That's why it is considered ambiguous. Both methods are a match before any constraints are checked.
If you explicitly say `Do<int?>` only the first method is a match, but then the constraint 'kicks in' and determines it is invalid because `int?` is not a reference type.

The second method will be chosen if you change it to:

```
public static string Do<T>(T? maybeValue, Func<T?, string> func)
    where T : struct
```